# Custom qt widget in QtDesigner

Tags: qt

I learned how to create a custom Qt Widget. I have two manuals for that. One is from the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) and the second one is from [*C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4*](http://www.civilnet.cn/book/embedded/gui/qt4/ch05lev1sec3.html). I tried those examples for creating custom Qt Widget and compiled them. After that, I put the output files ( .dll, .a file) into **QTSDKDirectory\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\plugins\designer**, but nothing was changed in QtDesigner.

Comment: If your custom Qt Widget is not very complex you may follow an alternative approach I described on a similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621618/qt-error-in-using-created-custom-widget-in-designer/5630348#5630348)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt Designer you have an About Plug-ins box. That's the first thing you want to check out. It will tell you whether your plug-in was loaded.

If your plug-in crashes, then it will crash Qt Designer, so that's not what was happening here.

One of the main reason for not loading a plug-in is incompatibility. In most cases, you compiled the plug-in in Debug and Qt Designer is a Release version.

if the plug-in loaded but you still don't see anything, the Group definition may be wrong or the create function may be failing somehow.